# Calling functions with variables that may not be defined

Tags: php

If I have the following statement:

```
$b = empty($a) ? "null" : "'$a'"
```

To avoid copy and paste, I'd like to put it in a function:

```
function x($a) {
  return empty($a) ? "null" : "'$a'"
}
```

So I can do:

```
$b = x($a); // $a is not defined, so PHP complains
$d = x($c); // same with $c
```

But then I would get an error from PHP because `$a` is not defined. Is there any way to accomplish this, except using the `@` operator?

**EDIT: I am refering to the error comes when calling x(), not inside x(). You know, you can do isset() and empty() on anything that is not defined, and PHP will never complain. But if you call a function with something undefined, PHP will complain. Which is the problem here.**

Comment: Why are you operating on a variable which may not be defined? What is the use-case?

Comment: Variables may be undefined for various reasons. In this case, I'd like to treat the variable as null rather than undefined.

Comment: I agree that you having an arbitrary number of undefined variables is a code smell. Only input provided by the user should be unknown, anything else should be in a defined state.

Answer (score 3):

First of all this is not an error but a notice so you could disable it.

Secondly you can define this parameter as being passed by reference to avoid the notice.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function x(&$a) {
    var_dump('inside', $a);
    return empty($a) ? "null" : "'$a'";
}

$a = 4;
var_dump('before', isset($a), isset($c));
$b = x($a);
$d = x($c);
var_dump('after', isset($a), isset($c));

var_dump($b, $d);
```

output:

```
string(6) "before" bool(true) bool(false) 
string(6) "inside" int(4) 
string(6) "inside" NULL
string(5) "after" bool(true) bool(false) 
string(3) "'4'" string(4) "null"
```

Comment: but why reference not producing any warning :)

Comment: probably because you can use references to "return" additional values. you can pass a non-existing variable name as parameter and function will "create" it. for example:
preg_match('/^def/', "abcdef", $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);

Comment: Then don't use `empty` inside the function because the parameter will never be "empty", at most it'll be *falsey*. Overall I don't like this approach though, since it'll also create the variable in the calling scope. You should know what variables are defined and for those where you can't guarantee it, `isset`/`empty` are the way to go.

Comment: @deceze i have added some tests to answer. indeed it seems to be NULL inside but if you don't explicitly assign it inside function it still seems to be not set in outside scope. so guess this is good enough for OP's use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
$a = 5;
$b = "hi";

function var_test($var) {
    global ${$var};
    return isset(${$var}) ? ${$var} : null;
}

var_dump(var_test("a"));
var_dump(var_test("b"));
var_dump(var_test("c"));
```

Cause `${"var_name"}` will resovle into `$var_name`

Comment: This is not a solution for arbitrary scopes though, only the global scope.

Answer (score -1):

As written here http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php you may do something like this:

```
function x($a=NULL) {
   return empty($a) ? "null" : "'$a'"
}
```

Comment: it will still give you a notice when you will try to call x() on undefined variable.

Comment: it gives you notice for `x($something_undefined);` but not for `x();`. But it will give you same notice for first use of anything undefined. Perhaps, this was the question, then I misunderstood it.